# Returned votes when question/answer is deleted

Tags: support, voting, deleted-posts

If I vote on a question/answer and it is deleted 3 days later (and I am out of votes today), do I get that vote back for today?

Comment: Maybe when you run out of votes do something else for a while...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I know what you are saying.   but I am addicted.  I usually switch to programmers for a little while, or answer a question, or edit questions,  or actually do what I am supposed to be doing.

Comment: So one more vote today is going to cure your addiction? Seriously. Get outside, enjoy the sun, talk to a friend, see a movie.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, it's cold outside.  I don't like, but I do other things. just curious how all these things work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  You get that vote back three days ago.  Sadly, you cannot use votes you have left over from three days ago.  (Even if you had a time machine you still couldn't, as you won't have gotten the votes back yet.)

Comment: I don't understand... is there a bug in the way votes are counted then? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week (I spent 40 votes/day all week => 160 | Malachi has 161!)

Comment: @retailcoder If a question is deleted *on the day the vote was cast* you get the vote back for today, not three days ago, which is a point in time still allowing you to use the vote you just got back.

Comment: So if I vote 40 times on 40 questions that get deleted, I get 40 votes back and I can vote another 40 times, and the users/voters tab will show 80 votes?

Comment: @retailcoder Yes.  It's been brought up before, the short answer is the community just doesn't *care* if people try to game that metric, it just doesn't really bother people.

Comment: -1 for making my brain hurt by including time travel in your answer. +1 for the imaginary hand-drawn circles that came with the headache.